# Lifting state from child component to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have 2 child components: a `Categories` select and a `Search` input text and submit button. They both have their own state. I have to use those two components in a parent page. I need to know in which category I have to do the search and to achieve this I think I should lift the state, so that the parent will handle it.

Basically I removed state from the child component and placed it on the parent, ending up with something like this (simplified code):

```
export default ParentPage = () => {

  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(0);

  const onSearch = () => {
    // search for searchString in the selected category
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Categories category={category} setCategory={setCategory} />
      <Search searchString={searchString} setSearchString={setSearchString} onSearch={onSearch} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Is this a good approach? It seems a bit verbose, is there a more compact way to pass the state and setState to child components?

Comment: Doesn't appear there is any cross dependencies for `Categories` to share state with `Search` and vice-versa, so in this case I'd say no, it isn't a good approach as you've now semi-coupled both components to `ParentPage`. But perhaps more is going on in your real code? **EDIT** Thanks for update, yes, lifting state to parent makes sense now.

Comment: Apologies, the Search contains an input and a submit. When you hit submit the onSearch is called and the parent will search in the selected category (I edited the post)

Comment: @devamat, then it's all good, this is when lifting state is needed

Answer (score 1):

In place of this:

```
<Categories category={category} setCategory={setCategory} />
<Search searchString={searchString} setSearchString={setSearchString} />
```

You can also use the below one, as you are keeping same name props as states :

```
<Categories {...{ category , setCategory }} />
<Search {...{ searchString , setSearchString }} />
```

---

> Note : But I can't see any purpose of lifting state up, from the provided
>   code, so can't say anything about it.

---

After the code update, you can do it something like this :

```
export default ParentPage = () => {

  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(0);

  const onSearch = () => {
    // search for searchString in the selected category

    // if you are filtering category and calling setCategory, then it's all good
    // else you need to pass `searchString` in `Categories` to filter the data

  }

  return (
    <>
      <Categories {...{category , setCategory }} />
      <Search {...{searchString , setSearchString , onSearch}} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean `{...{ searchString, setSearchString }}` ?

Comment: @devamat, yes, thannks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have prepared a complete example here. You need to pass child state from child to parent using callback and then you receive child's state on parent and send that state to another child.

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";
import Sibling from "../Sibling";

function CParent(props) {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

    function setOpeningValue(status) {
        console.log('From Child to Parent:' + status);
        setStatus(status);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Child setOpeningValue={setOpeningValue}/>
            <Sibling status={status}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default CParent;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Child to Parent communication
function Child(props) {
    const {setOpeningValue} = props;
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    function clickHandler() {
        setOpen(!isOpen);
        setOpeningValue(`changes is ${!isOpen}`);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Open</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Child;
```

**Sibling Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function Sibling(props) {
    const {status} = props;
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            From Child to Parent to Another Child (Sibling) {status}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Sibling;
```